# HTT, 4.3.2.4, Lurie , Kan Extensions

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, higher-category-theory

> I am completely lost with the remark at [4.3.2.4, pg 273](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~lurie/papers/HTT.pdf). It would be great if one could elaborate what is going on.

---

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

> Is not by *requirement* that $(C^0/C)^{\triangleright} \rightarrow D$ is a $p$-colimit?

Comment: Perhaps you may have missed the requirement that $C$ is an object of $C^0$ in remark ?

Comment: Ah, yes, I did not see that.